# renaming all files in a folder deletes all files

Tags: node.js

I am trying to rename all files in a folder but the current method im using is deleting all the files in that folder. Why is that happening and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```js
fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'blah')).forEach(file => {
  fs.rename(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'blah', file), file.replaceAll(' ', '~'), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Rename complete!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On unix systems (macOS, linux) the ~ symbol has a special meaning in a file path, you can't use it for a file name.

   So for example, `~/Music/blah.mp3` means `/User/John/Music/blah.mp3`. It's kind of like `.` or `..`. So you shouldn't use it for the name.
2. When renaming a file, you need to give the full absolute path to that file in the new name, not just the name of the file.

   So renaming `path.join(__dirname, 'blah.mp3')` into `'foo.mp3'` would move the file from `/User/John/a/b/blah.mp3` (depending on where "__dirname" is) to `/foo.mp3` (at the root of your system).
3. I think `readdirSync` returns an array of full paths, so you shouldn't need to prefix `file` with `__dirname/../blah`

Is it possible you're trying to rename "files that don't exist" (see point #3) into files that already exists (maybe your filename doesn't contain `' '` or maybe `'~'` gets ignored because of point #1). And when renaming, the docs do mention:

> In the case that newPath already exists, it will be overwritten.

(https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrenameoldpath-newpath-callback)

Comment: what is a good special character to replace space with that works with all sub systems?

Comment: People usually use `_` to replace spaces.